# jQuery Validation - IP Address validation problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate, validation

I have developed code of how to validate IP Address.

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src=
"http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $.validator.addMethod('IP4Checker', function(value) {
            var ip = "^(?:(?:25[0-5]2[0-4][0-9][01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}" +
                "(?:25[0-5]2[0-4][0-9][01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$";
                return value.match(ip);
            }, 'Invalid IP address');

            $('#form1').validate({
                rules: {
                    ip: {
                        required: true,
                        IP4Checker: true
                    }
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
```

**HTML**

```
    <input id="ip" name="ip" type="text"  /> 
    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
```

This script is working good but have one problem this script only check the IP block 0-255 numbers when i enter `100.100.100` it accept the IP address also when I enter any numeric value like `1234567` it also accept this value as IP address. so please help me regarding this problem

Thanks

Comment: This is duplicate to WHICH question ?